# How to display old articles?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I wanted to set created date of the articles, so I set the date of the articles to 2012-2-1 but after the setting the date of the articles it's not displaying in the front-end anymore now.

After doing a deep dive into this I saw the article in the back-end it isn't being published. It's saying `published, but has expired`.

So, can I not publish the old-dated articles?

Please, help me on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Do you use automatic publishing/unpublishing of articles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Published but has expired means that you have set a Finish Publishing date and that date is in the past. It sounds like you changed that date instead of the create date.

Comment: Thanks, I should only change the created date and/or start publishing not to finish publishing.

Comment: Correct. The creation date does not affect when an article displays. The start publish date allows you to keep an article hidden until some date in the future and the finish publish date allows you to remove an article after some date in the future.

Answer (score 0):

for created date You should change **Created Date** field you may accidentally changed **Start Publishing** or **Finish Publishing**